# Laravel - how to create custom 'with' method

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4

The question is in the title.
This is what I have been tried:

- I created `MyView` class extending `View`
- Added to the app aliases list
- I created method `withMyData()` inside that class like this:

(this is just example. It all works in a regular way)

```
$my_data = 'some data';
return $this->with( 'my_data', $my_data );
```

Then I tried:

```
View::make('some-page')->withMyData();
```

I got this error:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined offset: 0
```

tnx

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need a custom method?

Comment: I have two pages where I need to pass same data. I just don't want to repeat same code.

Comment: Then perhaps you want a view composer? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

Answer (score 1):

You definitely chose the wrong approach to pass something to every view. Use [view composers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers) instead.

```
View::composer('layout', function($view){
    $my_data = 'some data';
    $view->with('my_data', $my_data);
});
```

(`layout` would be the name of your view. Everytime it gets rendered the composer runs. You can also use wildcards `*` or an array of view names to target multiple views)

You can put this code in app/filters.php or create a new app/composers.php and include it at the end of app/start/global.php with:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

### Edit

You can already use `with*` as an alternative to `with('*'`. So:

```
$view->with('my_data', $my_data);
```

Can be written as:

```
$view->withMyData($my_data);
```

Comment: I also can validate that this is a better way

Comment: Tnx for answering and I apologize for not being more specific. The thing is that I want to pass a specific array with a same keys, but with a different values. I already used composer for a logged user information, and I don't think that this will work for me this time. Is it possible to create custom "with" method or not? Tnx again!

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, I think that this is it... but this is just an alias. It's not actually MY method with some operation in it, right? :(

Comment: Yes it's just an alias. What operation do you want to perform?